# Showing storage log on browser

Tags: laravel

Error show like that:

when i am hitting this url http://localhost:8000/log

```
Undefined variable: redirect_url (View: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\IRMS\local\resources\views\public_home\header.blade.php) (View: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\IRMS\local\resources\views\public_home\header.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): 
Undefined variable: redirect_url (View: C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\IRMS\\local\ esources\\views\\public_home\\header.blade.php) (View: C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\IRMS\\local\ esources\\views\\public_home\\header.blade.php) at C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\IRMS\\local\\storage\\framework\\views\\3a756e732746d6d2335e40e33b603bce42b4705f.php:17, ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: redirect_url (View: C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\IRMS\\local\ esources\\views\\public_home\\header.blade.php) at C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\IRMS\\local\\storage\\framework\\views\\3a756e732746d6d2335e40e33b603bce42b4705f.php:17, ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: redirect_url at C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\IRMS\\local\\storage\\framework\\views\\3a756e732746d6d2335e40e33b603bce42b4705f.php:17)
```

Comment: The problem is stated in log: Undefined variable `redirect_ur` in your `header.blade.php`

Comment: but why it is showing i have no route like  http://localhost:8000/log and when i am commenting that url from my blade also shows that error

Comment: Probably you commented the variable the **html way**. Since there is no relevant code in your question then we can't help you further

Comment: check your file `\resources\views\public_home\header.blade.php`. Better post the code

Comment: solved it. It has in this file: app/Modules/Web/routes/web.php... commented thisroute 
Route::get('/log', '\Srmilon\LogViewer\LogViewerController@index');